# Mongodb returns more than one result when using Take(1)

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I want to fetch only one row with C# LINQ:

```
collection.AsQueryable().Take(1).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Single();
```

I am getting the following error:

`Sequence contains more than one element`

Isn't this is what `Take(1)` is for?
**UPDATE1**
Here is the result of fetching only without single/first...

[image]

Comment: Say you took one. Why would you want to Sort ONE after?

Comment: @Mehrad I want to get the highest id. the _id is long number.

Comment: So shouldn't you first Sort it then `Take(1)` ?

Comment: Remove `Single()` from the end and try again. Let me know

Comment: @Mehrad I know FirstOrDefault will work. but isnt that whats Single meant for? taking one result and if there are more throw an exception? Why there are more than one result when I am using Take(1)

Comment: I didn't suggest to use `FirstOrDefault' anyways. What I was suggesting is to remove `Single()` and see what you receive.

Comment: @Mehrad . hmmmm odd, I am getting the correct result. Can it be that the Take(1) is doing the fetch itself? I am confused now.

Comment: put the full code in. I am not sure what are you assigning the result into.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66538/discussion-between-mehrad-and-shazam).

Comment: Would love to hear your opinion on this @BradleyDotNET.

Answer (score 3):

In my situation it works

```
        int[] grades = { 1 , 2, 3 };
        Console.WriteLine(grades.Take(1).Single());

        //the result is 
        // 1
```

More extensive example

```
        var a = new List<int>{10, 20, 30};
        var b = new List<int>{100, 200, 300};
        var grades = new List<List<int>>{a, b};
        Console.WriteLine(grades.Take(1).Single());
```

and the result produced

```
List<Int32> (3 items)
10 
20 
30
```

**Order of LINQ statement matters**

Check these two examples

```
        int[] grades = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        IEnumerable<int> topThreeGrades =
            grades.Take(3).OrderByDescending(grade => grade);

        Console.WriteLine("The top three grades are:");
        foreach (int grade in topThreeGrades)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(grade);
        }
```

produces

```
The top three grades are:
3
2
1
```

**However**

```
        int[] grades = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        IEnumerable<int> topThreeGrades =
            grades.OrderByDescending(grade => grade).Take(3);

        Console.WriteLine("The top three grades are:");
        foreach (int grade in topThreeGrades)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(grade);
        }
```

will produce

```
The top three grades are:
5
4
3
```